# I can follow through well on instructions

Tags: meaning

I want to express myself as a very dedicated person and I follow the guidelines very well.

Can I use this sentence to express that behavior?

> I can follow through well on instructions

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that's okay. It's very formal though. Might I suggest some simpler alternatives :

> - I play by the rules and only by the rules.
> - I always obey the rules.
> - I stick to the rules.

There are many more ways you can express yourself. But what you use and how you use it depends on the **occasion, the audience and the context**. So choose wisely. You don't want to sound too casual because if you do, the listener might not believe you. Keep it simple, keep it short and you're good to go.